# In Python, count unique key/value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, pattern-matching

I have a dictionary that is made with a list of values.  Some of these values are also keys or values in other key/value pairs in the dictionary.  I would simply like to count how many of these unique pairs there are in the dictionary.

Ex.
`dict = {'dog':['milo','otis','laurel','hardy'],'cat':['bob','joe'],'milo':['otis','laurel','hardy','dog'],'bob':['cat','joe'],'hardy':['dog']}`

I need to count the number of key/value pairs that do not have share a key/value with another in the dict.  For example the above should count to only 2, those connected to dog and cat.  Even though milo is unique to dog, dog is also in the key/value pair 'hardy' and both of these should therefore be counted together (ie, only 1). (See comments below)
I have tried to go about it by replacing a key (key A) that exists in the values of another key (key B) with 'key B', without success however as I cannot specify key B correctly.

```
for keys, values in dict.iteritems():

    for key,value in dict.iteriterms():
            if key in values:
                dict[keys] = dict.pop(key)
```

Is there an easier method?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: So you want to find how many values contain elements that are not in any other value's list? In the case of `dog` the unique element is `milo` and in the case of `cat` the unique element is `bob`?

Comment: @Gabe Now that I reread the question, I believe to have answered it wrongly. :(

Comment: @Gabe, yes those are unique, but my goal is to count how many key/value pairs do not share any other items (even in the remaining elements attached to the key) with the rest of the dict.  If u r suggesting to look for unique items in the dictionary, this will not work all of the time because if just one of the other values is elsewhere in the dictionary, it should not be counted separately.  Thanks for that clarification however in the initial question.

Comment: I've answered, but now I'm having doubts if what I answered is actually what you wanted. The code you show won't work, because you're not allowed to remove values from a dictionary while you iterate over it. But is sounds like it isn't conceptually right either. Can you give some additional examples of input and output (with fewer values, preferably, so it's more obvious what the logic you need is!).

Comment: I think the biggest confusion comes from the use of "pairs". The usual meaning for that in the context of a dictionary is the key (e.g. `"hardy"`) and its associated value (e.g. the list `["dog"]`). You seem to want the pair to only include one of the values from the list, or something (it's not clear). Can you try to explain what exactly you want counted without using "pairs"?

Comment: By pairs, I meant a key and it's associated values.  My goal is to separate those keys/values that have nothing in common with other keys/values.  If a key is in another value, both keys and each of their values should be counted as 1 key/value.  If a value is in another key, or other value list, again, these both should be counted as a single key/value.  If not, then it is a separate key/value and now should be counted separately. My apologies for the confusion.  I would be more than happy to illustrate this differently as needed.  Cheers

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to count the number of [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) in a graph. There are well known algorithms for that. I'll update my answer to show one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, your dictionary is the adjacency map of a graph and you're trying to find the sets of [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29). The regular algorithm (using a depth- or breadth-first search) may not work correctly since your graph is not undirected (e.g. you have edges from `"bob"` and `"cat"` to `"joe"`, but none coming out from `"joe"`).

Instead, I suggest using a [disjoint set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). It's not hard to build one using a dictionary to handle the mapping of values to parents. Here's an implementation I wrote for a previous question:

```
class DisjointSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = {}
        self.rank = {}

    def find(self, element):
        if element not in self.parent: # leader elements are not in `parent` dict
            return element
        leader = self.find(self.parent[element]) # search recursively
        self.parent[element] = leader # compress path by saving leader as parent
        return leader

    def union(self, leader1, leader2):
        rank1 = self.rank.get(leader1,0)
        rank2 = self.rank.get(leader2,0)

        if rank1 > rank2: # union by rank
            self.parent[leader2] = leader1
        elif rank2 > rank1:
            self.parent[leader1] = leader2
        else: # ranks are equal
            self.parent[leader2] = leader1 # favor leader1 arbitrarily
            self.rank[leader1] = rank1+1 # increment rank
```

And here's how you could use it to solve your problem:

```
djs = DisjointSet()
all_values = set()
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    all_values.add(key)
    all_values.update(values)
    for val in values:
        l1 = djs.find(key)
        l2 = djs.find(val)
        if l1 != l2:
            djs.union(l1, l2)

roots = {djs.find(x) for x in all_values}
print("The number of disjoint sets is:", len(roots))
```

The first part of this code does two things. First it builds a set with all the unique nodes found anywhere in the graph. Secondly, it combines the nodes into disjoint sets by doing a union wherever there's an edge.

The second step is to build up a set of "root" elements from the disjoint set.

Comment: I like this answer and the way that you explained it.  This counts to 3 for the dictionary above however.  
Can you explain how '{v[0] for v in inverted_dict.values() if len(v) == 1}' ensures that the values are unique?  Even if the values are unique, it is not comparing these to other keys in the dictionary, and could possibly over estimate the count.

Comment: @Vince: The curly brackets in that statement make it a set comprehension, so any duplicated values get dropped. I think I have not understood the problem correctly, so I'll try to rewrite my answer (I'm counting something different than what you want).

Comment: I am not sure if you have seen it, but I tried to explain the problem more clearly above under the initial question.  Cheers

Comment: Wow lots to learn with this addition.  Thanks, my_sets was not defined, you meant len(roots) right?  Also, so if I understand correctly, if I had edges coming from joe, and other nodes required for a directed graph, the above code would not work?  How hard would it be to constuct one that does?  Thanks so much for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
values = {'dog':['milo','otis','laurel','hardy'],
          'cat':['bob','joe'],
          'milo':['otis','laurel','hardy','dog'],
          'bob':['cat','joe'],
          'hardy':['dog']}

result = []

for x in values.iteritems():
    y = set([x[0]] + x[1])
    if not any([z for z in result if z.intersection(y)]):
        result.append(y)

print len(result)
```

Note that you shouldn't call a variable `dict` because you're shadowing the built-in type `dict`.

Your goal is unclear, but you can modify the construction of the `y` `set` to meet your needs.

Comment: On this and another test file, this seems to do the trick.  Just to clarify, what does y = set([x[0]] + x[1]) mean exactly?  Thanks for your help, I need to look more into sets...

Comment: @Vince `[x[0]]` is a list with one element (`x[0]` being that element). `[x[0]] + x[1]` is adding this one-element list to the list that is in `x[1]`. So `[x[0]] + x[1]` is a list containing key and values together. And calling `set()` on it creates a set containing the items from this list.

Comment: I am finding that this solution works, but as the relationships between the key/values becomes more complex (more values with more possible connections), it starts to over count them.  I am going to look more into sets.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to describe a graph-like structure, and you're looking at whether the keys appear in a value list.  Since you are only interested in count, you don't have to worry about future value lists, when iterating through the dict, so this should work:

```
d = {'dog': ['milo','otis','laurel','hardy'],'cat': ['bob','joe'],'milo': 'otis','laurel','hardy','dog'], 'bob': ['cat','joe'], 'hardy': ['dog']}
seen = set()
unique = []
for key, values in d.iteritems():
    if key not in seen:
        unique.append(key)
    seen = seen.union(values)
print(len(unique))
```

Note that the actual values contained in `unique` are dependent on dict ordering, are are only keys, not values.  If you are actually trying to some sort of network or graph analysis, I suggest you make use of a library such as [networkx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx/)

Comment: I could not get this to work unfortunately, but you are right that this is part of a network analysis.  Networkx looks like something I can explore, thanks so much.